# is there a way to program minecraft plugins with python?

Tags: python, minecraft

is there a way to program block game plugins with python?

I researched this topic and got this:

https://github.com/Macuyiko/minecraft-python/

https://github.com/Jycraft/jycraft

(there is not much to add)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any possibility to actually program a plugin in python. In the end it has to be translated in java anyway, in order to run it. (Because Minecraft runs on Java) Both projects you have linked are doing so. I would recommend to use [Java](https://www.java.com/de/) or [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) to program Minecraft plugins.